# Getting text within a div of a div that is the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically, I have some buttons

```
<div class="button">
  <!--Some other stuff-->
  <div class="id">HD5sjW</div>
</div>

<div class="button">
  <!--Some other stuff-->
  <div class="id">yqWH3X</div>
</div>

<div class="button">
  <!--Some other stuff-->
  <div class="id">KWZy5V</div>
</div>
```

and I wanted to use JavaScript to link to another page and I couldn't find an explanation so this is what I came up with and obviously doesn't work at all - how am I meant to do this?

```
$('.button').click(function () {
        confirm("http://domain.com/thing?id=" + $(this + " .id").text());
});
```

The confirm is just for a blatant output

---

As another thing, how should I structure my questions better and type of title?

Comment: Why aren't you using real `<button>` elements? Without `tabindex`, `role`, etc these "buttons" won't be accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) or a context parameter in the jQuery function.

```
$('.button').hover(function () {
        confirm("http://domain.com/thing?id=" + $(".id", this).text());
});

$('.button').hover(function () {
        confirm("http://domain.com/thing?id=" + $(this).find('.id').text());
});
```

Comment: This is cleaner than mine. I would caution you on using .hover though. Check out this fiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/aeLLr2s1/ and you'll see that the confirm box gets triggered multiple times when you use .hover.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `.click()` using `.hover()` will cause the confirm box to trigger multiple times.

```js
$('.button').click(function () {
        //find out which buttton this is
        var currentBtn = $('.button').index( $(this) );
        
        //use currentBtn to find its matching id div using `:eq()`
        var currentId = $('.id:eq('+currentBtn+')').text();
        confirm("http://domain.com/thing?id=" + currentId)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
  <!--Some other stuff-->
  <div class="id">HD5sjW</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="button">
  <!--Some other stuff-->
  <div class="id">yqWH3X</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="button">
  <!--Some other stuff-->
  <div class="id">KWZy5V</div>
</div>
```